# Object Detection: Training Requried or No Training Required?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

This question is related to Object detection, and basically, detecting any "known" object. For an example, imagine I have the below objects.

1. Table
2. Bottle.
3. Camera
4. Car

I will take 4 photos from all of these individual object. One from left, another from right, and other 2 from up and down. I originally thought it is possible to recognize these objects with these 4 photos per each, because you have the photos in all 4 angles, no matter how you see the object you can detect it.

But I got confused with someones idea about training the engine with thousands of positive and negative images from each object. I really don't think this is required.

So simply speaking, my question is, in order to identify an object, do I need these thousands of positive and negative objects? Or else simply 4 photos from 4 angles is enough?

I am expecting to use OpenCV for this.

**Update**

Actually the main thing is something like this.. Imagine that I have 2 laptops. One is Dell and the other one is HP. Both are laptops but you know, they have clearly visible differences including the Logo. Can we do this using [Feature Description](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html#feature-description)? If not, how "hard" the "training" process? How many pics needed?

**Update 2**
I need to detect "specific" objects. Not all the cars, all the bottles etc. For an example, the "Maruti Car Model 123" and "Ferrari Car Model 234" are both cars but different. Imagine I have the pictures of Maruti and Ferrari of above mentioned models, then I need to detect them. I don't have to worry about other cars or vehicles, or even other models of Maruti and Ferrari. But the above mentioned "Maruti Car Model 123" should be identified as "Maruti Car Model 123" and above mentioned "Ferrari Car Model 234"should be identified as "Ferrari Car Model 234". How many pictures do I need for this?

Comment: Depends on what sort of algorithm you are going to use.

Comment: You do realize that you're taking 2D photos of 3D objects? Because the different rotations happen in 3D space, yet the recognition has to happen in 2D space. If you can reconstruct the 3D object, recognition in 3D space would be a lot easier, but that's a big IF.

Comment: @user2079303: Please have a look at my update to the question.

Comment: @MSalters: Please have a look at my update to the question.

Comment: @HashMap do you want to detect ANY bottle/table/camera/car or one specific bottle/table/camera/car? If one specific non deforming object is what you want to detect, a couple of pictures of THAT specific object might be enough without any training. On the other hand, if you want to detect a porsche carrera, a couple of pictures of a ford focus might be of no help ;)

Comment: @Micka: You are correct, I need to detect "specific" objects. Not all the cars, all the bottles etc. For an example, the "Maruti Car Model 123" and "Ferrary Car Model 234" are both cars but different. Imagine I have the pictures of maruti and ferrary, then I need to detect them. I don't have to worry about other cars or vehicles, or even other models of Maruty and Ferrary. But the above mentioned "Maruti Car Model 123" should be identified as "Maruti Car Model 123" and above mentioned "Ferrary Car Model 234"should be identified as "Ferrary Car Model 234". How many pictures do I need for this?

Comment: at least one of each object side that might be visible in later detections, the more the better. but if those car models are modified by the user or altered in some other way (color/design etc) your reference model might not be correct enough again, there you would need to train a model. But why don't you just try it without training?

Comment: maybe have a look at: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep576/05wi/lectures/sift_jiwon.ppt

Comment: @Micka: If the user modified it, then for now, we can ignore it.

Comment: @Micka: wow! amazing link!!! you got more like this? wow!

Comment: @Micka: Can I have some idea about "how many pics" I need for training and how to do it? According to the link you provided, it seems like we have to give 1 image in case of 2D. Since mine is 3D, 4 images from 4 sides would be enough?

Comment: Have no practical experience but I would think of 8 images including the pictures between 2 "sides". Maybe search for original Sift paper (by Lowe). Afair they used some database too

Comment: @HashMap google for this paper too: Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints - UBC ... at the end they give some information about basic obj recogn. and cite some of their other paper!

Comment: @Micka: Thanks, all your advise work for a real time situation right? which means camera sees the object and identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. If you want to detect a specific object and you don't need to account for view point changes, you can use 2D features:
   http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html
2. To distinguish between 2 logos, you'll probably need to build a detector for each logo which will be trained on a set of images. For example, you can train a Haar cascade classifier.
3. To distinguish between different models of cars, you'll probably need to train a classifier using training images of each car. However, I encountered an application which does that using a nearest neighbor approach - it just extracts features from the given test image and compares it to a know set of images of difference car models.

Also, I can recommend some approaches and packages if you'll explain more on the application.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. So yeah, as I have mentioned in my question imagine I already have pictures of "Maruti Car Model 123" and "Ferrary Car Model 234". So if the camera sees this "Maruti Car Model 123"(real time), then it should identify it as it is. It should not confuse it with the Ferrary. We don't have to consider about other cars. "Later" in this application I might have to identify the door, light, etc of this car too. I look forward for your response.

Comment: I would try using Decaf features:
https://github.com/UCB-ICSI-Vision-Group/decaf-release/

Comment: Thanks! Is this is something like https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep576/05wi/lectures/sift_jiwon.ppt ?

Comment: Thanks. These advises work for the real time situation right? Which means camera sees the object and identify it in real time.

Comment: Perhaps for real time detection, you should try Caffe:

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/

It's faster than Decaff

Comment: Thanks a lot. We still have to train images right? How many images in do I have to put into this "teaching process".  I will take images from all 4 sides, so 2 images per side is enough? That make 8 images.

Comment: The process I'm suggesting is the following: in the training phase, extract features using Decaf from a lot of images and train a classifier. In the test phase, given a test image, extract descriptor from it and feed them to the classifier.

I think you'll need a lot more than 8 images. Take a lot of images in different lightning conditions and from different view points.

Comment: hmm..Lot of images means thousands per object? Or 20-30 ? actually I only need to detect a specific objects, so if there are thousands of objects then there will be multi millions of images!

Comment: It's hard to say exactly how many images you'll need. It also depends on how constrained the conditions of lightning changes and pose changes. Start with a few dozens and see how well that performs.

Comment: Thanks, how long this process take?

Comment: Extracting decaf features takes about 1-3 seconds per image (on my computer). I'm not sure how long the training will elapse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and continuous support. You mentioned something about "Nearest Neighbor" thing right? The link I provided to you is something like that? I just saw it has been used to identify vehicle parts and locations! May I know your idea on this please? Thanks again for your continuous support

Comment: Basically, you can extract features from a large set of training samples. Given a test image, extract features from it and find the closest feature of the test image in the training set. You can classify the test image as the same class as it's closest feature in the training set (or more commonly referred as it's "nearest neighbor")

Comment: Hello, I have one more question. After the training, what is the output? A XML file?

Comment: Basically, it depends on the implementation and the environment (which classifier are you training? in which programming language? OpenCV or Matlab). I'm not sure what are the outputs in case that you're using OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked in the title, if you want to be able to determine what the object in the picture is you need a supervised algorithm (a.k.a. trained). Otherwise you would be able to determine, in some cases, the edges or the presence of an object, but not what kind of an object it is. In order to tell what the object is you need a labelled training set.

Regarding the contents of the question, the number of possible angles in a picture of an object is infinite. If you just have four pictures in your training set, the test example could be taken in an angle that falls halfway between training example A and training example B, making it hard to recognize for your algorithm. The larger the training set the higher the probability of recognizing the object. Be careful: you never reach the absolute certainty that your algorithm will recognize the object. It just becomes more likely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the main thing is something like this.. Imagine that I have 2 laptops. One is Dell and the other one is HP. Both are laptops but you know, they have clearly visible differences including the Logo. Can we do this using Feature Description?(http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html#feature-description) If not, how "hard" the "training" process? How many pics needed?